# OpenCV on Yocto Linux

Tags: opencv

How do I install openCV on Yocto Project? I am trying to use Intel Atom Board for Image Processing Project. What's the alternative if openCV is not compatible, openCL? Please help!

Answer (score 2):

Just add opencv in your image recipe or in your local.conf

```
 `IMAGE_INSTALL  += "opencv"`
```

Answer (score 2):

openCV creates dynamic package names for each library so unfortunately

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "opencv"
```

will not install any libraries. Instead install specific libraries, example below. Note that you still need to install opencv in case you build an SDK

```
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "opencv libopencv-core libopencv-imgproc"
```

Comment: What does "opencv" add to image,  if it is not a library ?

Comment: You only need to add the opencv package if you are building an SDK. Include files are part of the main opencv-dev package, not the domain specific sub packages.